# Exclude child project files when building parent project

Tags: c#, csproj

I have an ASP Core project that references a second project. Both have an appsettings.json file. I only want to include only the parent projects when building the parent project but still include appsettings.json in the child project when the child project is built individually.

If not possible it would be fine to output Child Project into a sub directory to avoid clashing.

Child csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>ChildProject</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>ChildProject</PackageId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Parent csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>2.0.0</VersionPrefix>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>ParentProject</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>ParentProject</PackageId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ChildProject\ChildProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```